# Convexity of trace function involving product of matrices and inverse

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis

I am investigating the convexity property of trace (R⋅inv(I+ η⋅Xᴴ⋅X⋅R)) with respect to matrix X. Here, X is a T×N matrix, and R is a positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix and η is a scalar constant. Any insights to address this will help. I am working on minimizing this function with certain constraints on X.